# how to assign drive geometry in windows

Tags: hard-drive

I've got an old, old hard drive from back in the day when HDs were 120MB in size. When I connect it via a USB-IDE adapter in Windows, the operating system recognizes it and loads the driver, but does not recognize the disk geometry and assigns a value of "0" to everything: 0 sectors, 0 cylinders, 0 bytes, etc.

I'd like to get this drive working so that I can see what's on there and pull off anything I might want. So I'd like some practical suggestions on things I can try from home. For example, is there a way to manually set the disk geometry in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to show up to the computer as an IDE device but as a regular USB Storage device, the same as any other USB drive.  Any incompatibility might be with the adapter itself trying to access the IDE device.

Comment: in this particularly case, I really doubt the incompatibility lies with the adapter. Of course the way to know for sure, is to connect it to the IDE bus which I will take as a next step .... but the problem probably lies with the HD hardware. It does sound like it spins up smoothly, but if I'm not mistaken I believe I have connected it via IDE under both Windows and Linux before, to no avail.